# Getting arrayindexoutofbounds when reading from file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, indexoutofboundsexception

I have this small problem of mine, where I would be getting arrayindexoutofboundsexception when trying to read from file. I don't know of a better or more detailed way of explaining it, so I will paste the code and the error below.
This is all in the mainmethod of my program.

```
    File fila;
    String[] innlesningsarray=new String[500];

    try{
        Scanner innFil=new Scanner(new File("/uio/hume/student-u77/makrist/Downloads/akronymer.txt"));

        while(innFil.hasNext()){
        for(int i=0; i<500; i++){

        // String innLest=br.nextLine();
            innlesningsarray=innFil.nextLine().split("\t");
            System.out.println(innlesningsarray[i]);
            System.out.println(innFil.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println("test");
        }
        System.out.println("Test2");

    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
    }
    }
}
```

After this part I have an object of Acronyms and stuff, but no errors there...

The error:

> AA        Auto Answer
>
> AAB  All-to-All Broadcast
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: Instead of `print(e)` you should write `e.printStackTrace()`. This will print a lot of useful information about the exception.

Comment: The posted code is not correct, but I don't see how it can result in an IOOBE. That exception comes from elsewhere (or possibly a different version/build of the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do `nextLine()` twice in the loop. This will read 2 lines in your file.

`while(innFil.hasNext())` can return `true` if you have 1 line left. Next thing you do is reading 2 lines in that while-loop. Since there is only 1 line left, you'll get your exception.

You have it placed in a for-loop as well. That means you do 500*2 times the `readLine()` method, while you only check for 1 line.

Try the following:

```
try{
    Scanner innFil=new Scanner(new File("/uio/hume/student-u77/makrist/Downloads/akronymer.txt"));

    while(innFil.hasNext()){
        for(int i=0; i<500; i++){
            String theReadLine = innFil.nextLine();
            innlesningsarray=theReadLine.split("\t");
            System.out.println(innlesningsarray[i]);
            System.out.println(theReadLine);
        }
        System.out.println("test");
    }
    System.out.println("Test2");

    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e.printStackTrace);
    }
}
```

This solves a possible error with the `nextLine()` method. You should be sure `innlesningsarray` actually has 500 or more entries, else you will receive your exception. Make sure that your akronymer.txt file has the string `\t` 500 or more times in it!

I also changed your `catch`-code. Instead of `print(e)` you should write `e.printStackTrace()`. This will print a lot of useful information about the exception. Thanks to Roland Illig for that comment!

Comment: Where? O.O One is commented out and the other is a printline. This happened before I put in the printline as well. The array has 500 spaces, and the txt-file is long

Comment: If you place it in a printline, it still reads the line and puts the marker after that line.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the IOOBE, since `i` is independent of `nextLine`.

Comment: As above user stated, this solves a possible error with the `nextLine()` method. You should be sure `innlesningsarray` actually has 500 or more entries, else you will receive your exception.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks